# how to replace dot with hyphen through sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a file which contains IP addresses and I want to replace "." with "-" through sed.

I am using below command:

```
sed 's/./-/g' iplist.txt
```

after running this command the output which I am getting is `-------------`, it replaces whole IP address with "-".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sed uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to find text that needs to be changed, and in regular expressions a `.` means to match any character. Your command is telling sed to change any character to a `-`.

To fix this, you need to escape the `.` by putting a `\` in front of it, to tell sed to only match on actual periods:

```
sed 's/\./-/g' iplist.txt
```

Comment: or include it within bracket `[.]`

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `tr(1)`:

```
tr . - < infile > outfile
```